# How to prove $2^{2\left(n+1\right)}-2^{2n}-3$ = $3\left(2^{2n}-1\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across a question which asked me to prove $2^{2\left(n+1\right)}-2^{2n}-3$ = $3\left(2^{2n}-1\right)$ and I tried expanding it to 
 $2^{\left(2n\right)}\cdot 2^2-2^{2n}-3$ ,  But that didn't help.
 Then I tried $\left(3+1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}-\left(3+1\right)^n-3$ but I'm unable to extract the 3 out. I think it is required to use binomial theorem but I'm not sure how to extract the 3 out.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $2^2 = 4$ and collect like terms from your first attempt.

Comment: Hint: $\;4 \cdot 2^{2n}-2^{2n}-(4-1) = (4-1)\left(2^{2n}-1\right)\,$.

Comment: You may use induction, also.

Comment: The book says to use induction, but they didn't really explain what it is and how to use it.

Comment: @strangeindian `The book says to use induction` Then why did you tag it as `binomial-theorem`? That's the last thing you'd use for this. `but they didn't really explain what it is` That would be odd for a book to advise something that wasn't already introduced earlier. Were there some prerequisites assumed, maybe?

Comment: @dxiv The book is quite odd, it doesn't explain much.It explain everything from scratch, even HCF and LCM!  a) Prove using binomial theorem and b) Prove using induction. I knew a bit about binomial and therefore tagged it as such.

Comment: Hmm, if they ask for both binomial and induction you will have to do that.  But the most straightforward way will be to notice $a*2^2- a -3= (2^2-1)a-3=3a-3=3 (a-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
4\cdot2^{2n}−2^{2n}−3&=4\cdot2^{2n}−2^{2n}−(4−1)\\
&=2^{2n}(4-1)−(4−1)\\
&=(2^{2n}-1)(4-1)\\
&=3(2^{2n}-1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

For the induction approach, we first have to verify that this holds when $n=0$ or $n=1$, depending on which you want to be your base case.  When $n=0$, we get $4-1-3=3(1-1)$, which is true.

Now, let us assume that the formula holds for $n=k$.  That is, $2^{2(k+1)}-2^{2k}-3=3(2^{2k}-1)$.

Let us attempt to evaluate $2^{2((k+1)+1)}-2^{2(k+1)}-3$, which is the left hand side when $n=k+1$.

$$2^{2((k+1)+1)}-2^{2(k+1)}-3=4(2^{2(k+1)}-2^{2k}-3+3)-3$$

where we added and subtracted 3 so that we had something in the form of the left hand side when $n=k$.  Using our induction hypothesis, we then have

$$ 4(2^{2(k+1)}-2^{2k}-3+3)-3=4(3(2^{2k}-1)+3)-3=3((4(2^{2k}-1)+4)-1).$$

The final bits of algebraic manipulation are left as an exercise to the reader.